# Adding Color to an edge

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm trying to do a youtube tutorial and it involves making cupboards in a wall. What I did was make loop cuts matching my reference image to carve out cupboards but I want to make it look like there's space between the cupboards. Is there a way to give an edge color? Or is there another way I could be doing this. Thanks! I'll include a screenshot[image].

Comment: "Mark Sharp" provides sharpness to the edges its under  EditMode-Edge-Mark Sharp

Comment: you can't give color to an edge, but if you slightly bevel the edge you'll have a face and you can give color to the face

Comment: .. and the bevel / bevel modifier has a material index setting, so you could color with that, if you wanted to

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions!